# Error al guardar combobox en java y mysql

Tags: java

Tengo dos tabas ***empleado y distrito***,el comboBox de empleado  me lista perfectamente con la base de datos de Distrito.El problema es que cuando intento guardar me sale un error.

> com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'dis' at row 4

Aqui esta el codigo

***CLASE EMPLEADO :*** Esta clase tiene un relaciona con ***distrito***

```java
public class EMPLEADO {

    private String codigo;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;
    private Integer dni;
    private Integer celular;
    private String sexo;
    private Date fec_nac;
    private Date fec_reg;
    private DISTRITO distrito;
    private String correo;
    private String direccion;
    private PERFIL perfil;
    private String usuario;
    private String contraseña;
    public EMPLEADO() {
        super();
    }

    public String getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApellido() {
        return apellido;
    }

    public void setApellido(String apellido) {
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }

    public Integer getDni() {
        return dni;
    }

    public void setDni(Integer dni) {
        this.dni = dni;
    }

    public Integer getCelular() {
        return celular;
    }

    public void setCelular(Integer celular) {
        this.celular = celular;
    }

    public String getSexo() {
        return sexo;
    }

    public void setSexo(String sexo) {
        this.sexo = sexo;
    }

    public Date getFec_nac() {
        return fec_nac;
    }

    public void setFec_nac(Date fec_nac) {
        this.fec_nac = fec_nac;
    }

    public Date getFec_reg() {
        return fec_reg;
    }

    public void setFec_reg(Date fec_reg) {
        this.fec_reg = fec_reg;
    }

    public DISTRITO getDistrito() {
        return distrito;
    }

    public void setDistrito(DISTRITO distrito) {
        this.distrito = distrito;
    }

    public String getCorreo() {
        return correo;
    }

    public void setCorreo(String correo) {
        this.correo = correo;
    }

    public String getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
    }

    public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }

    public PERFIL getPerfil() {
        return perfil;
    }

    public void setPerfil(PERFIL perfil) {
        this.perfil = perfil;
    }

    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public String getContraseña() {
        return contraseña;
    }

    public void setContraseña(String contraseña) {
        this.contraseña = contraseña;
    }

    public static String GrabarEmpleado() {
        return "call GrabarEmpleado(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    }


    /*listado de combo*/
    public static String ListarCombo() {
        return "SELECT * FROM  DISTRITO";
    }
    public static String ListarComboPerfil() {
        return "SELECT * FROM  PERFIL";
    }
}
```

***CLASE DISTRITO : *** Esta clase es de distrito y lo relaciona con Empleado

```
public class DISTRITO {

    private String cod_dis;
    private String nom_dis;

    public DISTRITO(String cod_dis, String nom_dis) {

        this.cod_dis = cod_dis;
        this.nom_dis = nom_dis;
    }
    public DISTRITO() {

    }

    public String getCod_dis() {
        return cod_dis;
    }

    public void setCod_dis(String cod_dis) {
        this.cod_dis = cod_dis;
    }

    public String getNom_dis() {
        return nom_dis;
    }

    public void setNom_dis(String nom_dis) {
        this.nom_dis = nom_dis;
    }

}
```

***Controlador empleado**** Aqui esta la logica del guardado del empleaco con distrito

```java
package pe.com.sistema.Inventario.Controlador;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;

import pe.com.sistema.Inventario.Pojo.EMPLEADO;

public class EmpleadoDAO {

    private ConexionDAO con = new ConexionDAO();
    private Connection cn = con.getConection();
    private PreparedStatement pstm = null;
    private ResultSet rs;
    public Integer totalRegistro;

    private static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("pe.com.sistema.Inventario.Controlador.EmpleadoDAO");

    public int GrabarEmpleado(EMPLEADO e) {
        int rpta = 0;
        String sql = EMPLEADO.GrabarEmpleado();

        try {
            pstm = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pstm.setString(1, e.getCodigo());
            pstm.setString(2, e.getNombre());
            pstm.setString(3, e.getApellido());
            pstm.setInt(4, e.getDni());
            pstm.setInt(5, e.getCelular());
            pstm.setString(6, e.getSexo());
            pstm.setDate(7, (java.sql.Date) e.getFec_nac());
            pstm.setDate(8, (java.sql.Date) e.getFec_reg());
            pstm.setString(9, e.getDistrito().getCod_dis());
            pstm.setString(10, e.getCorreo());
            pstm.setString(11, e.getDireccion());
            pstm.setString(12, e.getPerfil().getCod_perfil());
            pstm.setString(13, e.getUsuario());
            pstm.setString(14, e.getContraseña());

            rpta = pstm.executeUpdate();

            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, " EXITO !! " + " \n LOS DATOS SE GUARDARON");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, " ERROR !! " + " \n LOS DATOS NO SE GUARDARON");
            System.out.println("El error es: " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rpta;

    }

    public void ListarCombo(JComboBox<String> cboDistrito) {

        String sql = EMPLEADO.ListarCombo();

        try {
            Statement st = (Statement) cn.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            cboDistrito.addItem("    --- Seleccionar --- ");
            while (rs.next()) {

                cboDistrito.addItem(rs.getString("nombre"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }

    public void ListarComboPerfil(JComboBox<String> cboPerfil) {

        String sql = EMPLEADO.ListarComboPerfil();

        try {
            Statement st = (Statement) cn.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            cboPerfil.addItem("    --- Seleccionar --- ");
            while (rs.next()) {

                cboPerfil.addItem(rs.getString("nombre"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }

}
```

***Formulario*** este es el formulario del cliente y tiene todos los campos respectivos

```java
    protected void actionPerformedBtnGuardar(ActionEvent arg0) {
        if (txtNombre.getText().equals("") || txtApellido.getText().equals("") || txtDni.getText().equals("")
                || txtCelular.getText().equals("") ||  txtDireccion.getText().equals("")
                || txtCorreo.getText().equals("")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " ERROR !!! " + "\n COMPLETAR TODOS LOS CAMPOS  ", "ADVERTENCIA",
                    JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        } else {
            EMPLEADO em =new EMPLEADO();
            em.setCodigo(txtCodigo.getText());
            em.setNombre(txtNombre.getText());
            em.setApellido(txtApellido.getText());
            em.setDni(Integer.parseInt(txtDni.getText()));
            em.setCelular(Integer.parseInt(txtCelular.getText()));
            if (rdbtnH.isSelected()) {
                genero = "H";
            } else if (rdbtnM.isSelected()) {
                genero = "M";
            }
            em.setSexo(genero);
            em.setFec_nac(new java.sql.Date(dtNac.getDate().getTime()));
            em.setFec_reg(new java.sql.Date(dtReg.getDate().getTime()));
            DISTRITO d=new DISTRITO();
            d.setCod_dis(cboDistrito.getSelectedItem().toString());
            em.setDistrito(d);
            em.setDireccion(txtDireccion.getText());
            em.setCorreo(txtCorreo.getText());
            PERFIL p=new PERFIL();
            p.setNombre(cboPerfil.getSelectedItem().toString());
            em.setPerfil(p);
            em.setUsuario(txtUsuario.getText());
            em.setContraseña(txtContraseña.getText());
            int opcion=emDAO.GrabarEmpleado(em);

        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    void mostarCombo() {
        emDAO.ListarCombo(cboDistrito);
        emDAO.ListarComboPerfil(cboPerfil);
    }

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código con el que insertas los datos? El mensaje de error parece indicar que intentas guardar valores con un tamaño superior en la columna `dis`

Comment: Estimado Amigo es el Controlador en donde me sale error , es la lógica para insertar los datos , me puedes decir en que me equivoque es que quiero guardar el id del combobox en la base de datos,que se relaciona con distrito

Comment: El error ocurre al intentar insertar, por tanto, debes revisar el código que inserta  y/o mostrarlo en la pregunta para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: puedes poner el SQL de la tabla empleados?, a ver que estas almacenando en la columna 'dis'
Saludos

Comment: Estimado amigo he echo un Test a mi controlador y me ha funcionado bien , el error es en el formulario, cuando intento guardar el combo Box no me recono se el id